# Unwanted dash ("-") in implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump

Tags: terminal, ssh

### Intro

When open an ssh URL scheme (`ssh://[host]`), the Terminal app will be launched to handle the request, and `ssh` is launched without a shell.

### Symptom

In my case, if the host is configured to use `ProxyJump` command, the ssh command fails instantly while the host is ~200ms ping away.

For example, the `~/.ssh/config` file has the following content:

```
Host dest
HostName example.com
ProxyJump jump

Host jump
HostName jump.example.com
```

And upon running `open ssh://dest`, the command fails with the following output

```
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: -s: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

But if I run `ssh dest` in a proper shell (to an actual host), there is no such problem.

### Further Investigation

I find that the implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump differs:

When I run `ssh -vvv [host]` within a shell, it reports that

```
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' dest
```

---

When I run the same command without a shell (for example, by [replacing](https://d.pr/i/XEGLTG) the command with which to open a shell with `ssh -vvv [host]`), it reports that

```
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: -ssh -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' dest
...
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec -ssh -vvv -W '[example.com]:22' jump
...
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: -s: invalid option
```

### Question

As shown in previous section, I want to know why `ssh` becomes `-ssh` in `ProxyCommand`, and how to remove the dash.

### Reproducibility

I can reproduce this on a newly installed macOS using terminal. (macOS 10.15.5, OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3)

I cannot reproduce this when I use iTerm2 instead of Terminal.

I cannot reproduce this when using uBuntu.

### Workaround

Use `ProxyCommand` instead. But it is less convenient.